# Comparison of java map and python dictionary

Tags: java, python

java map:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myMap.put("1","one");
myMap.put("2","two");
```

python dictionary:

```
myDict = dict()
myDict['1'] = 'one'
myDict['2'] = 'two'
```

From a functional comparison, the two are very similar.

Can the map in java be considered the same thing as the dictionary in python?

Comment: Yes, it's the same concept.  Some of the details might be slightly different, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes at a high level :**

1. Python dictionary is implemented as hash tables underneath, so operations (get/put, bucketing) and performance (O(1) lookup) are similar to the HashMap implementation in Java.

**No at granular level :**

1. Map is just an interface in Java, with various implementations.
2. Python dictionary supports mix of types for values. Java Map doesn’t unless you define with Object.
3. Default hashcode algorithm is also different.

Comment: If you have a few spare minute, I would appreciate some details about the differences related to the `hashcode`.